# Python3 division: return int when there's no remainder and a float when there is a remainder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

In python3, integer division works differently than in python 2.7.3. Is there a way to ensure that a number that doesn't have a remainder after division is returned as an int, while a number that does have a remainder after division is returned as a float?

I'd like to be able to check:

```
if (instanceof(x/n, int)):
    # do something
```

The following occurs in python3:

```
>>> 4 / 2
2.0
>>> 5 / 2
2.5
```

Is there some way to make division act like this?

```
>>> 4 / 2
2
>>> 5 / 2
2.5
```

Answer (score 6):

You'd have to implement it yourself. Obvious approach would be:

```
def divspecial(n, d):
    q, r = divmod(n, d)  # Get quotient and remainder of division (both int)
    if not r:
        return q         # If no remainder, return quotient
    return n / d         # Otherwise, compute float result as accurately as possible
```

Of course, if you're just trying to check if division would be exact or not, don't use nonsense like the function above to check:

```
if isinstance(divspecial(x, n), int):
```

Just test the remainder directly:

```
if x % n == 0:  # If remainder is 0, division was exact
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to make it automatic, but you could always do a quick check afterwards to convert it:

```
r = 4/2
if r%1==0:
    r=int(r)
```

Comment: I'd be leery of a solution that assumes floating point division will reliably produce exact results even if the logic of the math dictates it should. Floating point error is a thing that messes up logic like this. `int` math is non-lossy in Python, `float` math is lossy, so if you need reliable results, you need to use `int` math first, and `float` as fallback.

Comment: `r = (10**20+1)/2` is an example where this fails.

Comment: That's true. I thought about it for cases where it would be less likely to fail, like the one in the question.